# Mock doesn't work in unittest for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I have a project structure like this:

```
py_test
   |
   +---my_module
   |    |  
   |    +--- __init__.py (empty)
   |    |
   |    +--- futil.py
   |
   +---test
        |
        +--- __init__.py (empty)
        |
        +--- futil_test.py
```

In **futil.py** I have the following:

```
from os import path


def check_exists(file_path):
    return path.exists(file_path)
```

In **futil_test.py** I'm trying to implement a unit test like this:

```
import mock
import unittest

from my_module.futil import check_exists


class TestExists(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('my_module.futil.os.path')        # <---leads to error, as well as my_module.os.path
    def test_exists(self, mock_path):
        mock_path.exists.return_value = True
        self.assertTrue(check_exists('ba'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I try to launch the unit test, it fails with the error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 367, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/home/antonio/devel/py/py_test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1322, in patched
    arg = patching.__enter__()
  File "/home/antonio/devel/py/py_test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1378, in __enter__
    self.target = self.getter()
  File "/home/antonio/devel/py/py_test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1548, in <lambda>
    getter = lambda: _importer(target)
  File "/home/antonio/devel/py/py_test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1235, in _importer
    thing = _dot_lookup(thing, comp, import_path)
  File "/home/antonio/devel/py/py_test/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1224, in _dot_lookup
    __import__(import_path)
ImportError: No module named os
```

In the example [here](https://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python) the similar construction seems to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "from os import path", will make path function part of futil. Instead of mocking "my_module.futil.os.path'" just mock "my_module.futil.path'", that should work.

Comment: Oh goddamn, thanks! Indeed, works fine

Comment: I have found this article very useful in the past http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/

Comment: pls, post this into the answer so that I could mark the question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"from os import path", will make path function part of futil. Instead of mocking "my_module.futil.os.path'" just mock "my_module.futil.path'", that should work.

I have found this article very useful in the past http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/